# playwright equivalent of find() in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, playwright, browser-automation

Is there a way to traverse through html elements in playwright like `cy.get("abc").find("div")` in cypress?

In other words, any `find()` equivalent method in playwright?

`page.locator("abc").find()` is not a valid method in playwright though :(

Comment: According to [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/find#Syntax), it seems like it tries to find the descendants of the given selector.. You want that? Or any other specific use case?

Comment: Need the same function in playwright where I can traverse through the html elements.
Do we have something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine the selectors, this will resolve to `div` below `abc`

```js
page.locator("abc div")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you assign the parent element handle to a variable, any of the `findBy*` functions (or `locator`) will search only in the parent element. An example below where the parent is a `div`, the child is a `button`, and we use `.locator()` to find the elements.

```js
test('foo', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('/foo');
  const parent = await page.locator('div');
  const child = await parent.locator('button');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the website https://www.example.com with the following HTML

```html
<body style="">
  <div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p>
      <a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

As mentioned by @agoff, you can use nested locator `page.locator('p').locator('a')` or you can specify the nested selector directly in the locator `page.locator('p >> a')`

```js
// @ts-check
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.webkit.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com/');

  // Here res1 and res2 produces same output
  const res1 = await page.locator('p').locator('a'); // nested locator
  const res2 = await page.locator('p >> a'); // directly specifying the selector to check the nested elements
  const out1 = await res1.innerText();
  const out2 = await res2.innerText();
  console.log(out1 == out2); // output: true
  console.log(out1); // output: More information...
  console.log(out2); // output: More information...

  // Traversal
  const result = await page.locator('p');
  const elementList = await result.elementHandles(); // elementList will contain list of <p> tags
  for (const element of elementList)
  {
    const out = await element.innerText()
    console.log(out);
  }
  // The above will output both the <p> tags' innerText i.e
  // This domain is for use in illustrative examples in...
  // More information...

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Since you mentioned that you need to traverse through the HTML elements, [elementHandles](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-element-handles) can be used to traverse through the elements specified by the locator as mentioned in the above code.